# How to switch from mysql-connector to mariadb?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb

I'm switching from `mysql-connector-java` to `mariadb-java-client`.

Question:

1) Is it a problem if the underlying database is still a `mysql` database?

2) Is it valid to use `jdbc:mariadb` as the url, even if the underlying db is still mysql?

3) I'm relying on `spring-boot` to create an initial `HikariDataSource` connection pool. Do I have to disable the internal mariadb-client connection pool?

Eg:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/tablename
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is it a problem if the underlying database is still a mysql database?

It is usually not a problem (unless you're using 8.0 with shiny new caching_sha2_password authentication).

> 2) Is it valid to use jdbc:mariadb as the url, even if the underlying db is still mysql?

Yes, it is valid. The only reason for jdbc:mariadb is that it helps to predictably load MariaDB's driver, even if MySQL's is also in classpath

> 3) I'm relying on spring-boot to create an initial HikariDataSource connection pool. Do I have to disable the internal mariadb-client connection pool?

If you did not enable driver's internal pool, it is not used. But maybe you should give internal pooling a try.